# Changing Black to Transparent in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying to replace the black background from gif/jpeg files with a transparent background, and because it's so tiring to manually do this one by one via PhotoShop, I thought of trying to use PHP. This is the code I'm using, but it doesn't work.

Why is that?

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif( 'items/item_spear06.gif' );
imagealphablending($image, true);
$transparentcolour = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $transparentcolour);
```

And the image I got was just the same image as last time just in png format.

---

*Update*

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif( 'items/sword/iv_sword_refined19.gif' );

//get pixel data
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, 10, 10);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

$index = imagecolorexact($image, $r, $g, $b); 
if ($index === -1) {
    $index = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
}
imagecolortransparent($image, $index);

var_dump($r, $g, $b);

// Save the image
imagepng($image, 'imagecolortransparent.png');
imagedestroy($image);
```

Now var_dump returns: `int(0) int(0) int(0)` when it should be `int(4) int(2) int(4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit out on a whim here but I guess that the color you have chosen here (black) already exists in the palette. So, what we do is to try to find that color in the palette and set that one to transparent, if it does not exist, then we can use `imagecolorallocate`

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif( 'items/item_spear06.gif' );
$index = imagecolorexact($image, 0, 0, 0); 
if ($index === -1) {
    $index = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
}
imagecolortransparent($image, $index);
```

To get the top-left pixels color

```
$index = imagecolorat($image, 0, 0);
$rgb = imagecolorsforindex($image, $index);
```

Comment: This worked. :) Thanks. Will accept in 4min.

Comment: Well this is weird. This same code doesn't work on the other images. Why could that be?

Comment: I might have gotten the if wrong, also, check the output on imagecolorallocate, it can fail if there is no room in the palette

Comment: Also, are you sure the other images have exact black as background?

Comment: This is the image that doesn't get replaced http://i.epvpimg.com/MB7ud.gif

Comment: thats not black (0,0,0) its (4,2,4) - you might be better off picking the top-left pixel and taking that pixel as transparent color?

Comment: How do I do that sir? Sorry I'm very new with this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29868/discussion-between-hank-and-zikdaljin)